# Azure Pipelines - Variable empty set in python

Tags: python, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure pipeline defined as:

```yaml
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      python3 script.py
      echo $(abc)
```

The `script.py` is loaded and contains the following:

```py
print('test_print')
print('##vso[task.setvariable variable=abc]abc')
print('set var')
```

Once I run this, the pipeline logs the print statements, however, the variable `abc` is empty.
I've played around w e.g. `subprocess` and using echo in the python script, but without good result.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why `echo $(abc)` returns an empty value?
It looks like python didn't set the variable, while it should.

Comment: Naive question, why should printing something from Python set a shell variable?

Comment: It's not a shell variable, it's a 'pipeline variable'. This is how azure pipelines work, to set a variable in the pipeline itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this doc: [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts)

> A script in your pipeline can define a variable so that it can be consumed by one of the subsequent steps in the pipeline.Set variables in scripts

It will not work on the current task, but the value can be used in the next tasks.

Refer to my sample:

```
 steps:
- bash: |
   python3 script.py
   
   
  displayName: 'Bash Script'

- bash: 'echo $(abc)'
  displayName: 'Bash Script'
```

In this case, it can get the expected value and can be used in the next tasks with the format: `$(abc)`.

**Result:**

[image]

**Update:**

**script.py**

```
print('test_print')
print('##vso[task.setvariable variable=abc]abc')
print('set var')
```

Comment: Hhm, not bad. I'll try that one.
However, I don't see Azure logging setting the variable... I'll try in a minute.

Comment: @KevinC I am using the same python script as yours. And the variable can work as expected in the next task. You can check the updated info

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems that my task `- task: Bash@3` didn't fetch the variable. when i use `- bash: echo $(abc)` it works.. really weird.